# Offscreen Page Limit in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I would like to load all pages inside `UIPageViewController` at the beginning. It's easy in Android with `setOffScreenPageLimit` method of view pager. Is it possible to achieve this in swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. You can manually pass on or two controllers at a time to your `UIPageViewController` or implement `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` that would call and fetch the controllers when needed.

> When defining a page view controller interface, you can provide the
>   content view controllers one at a time (or two at a time, depending
>   upon the spine position and double-sided state) or as-needed using a
>   data source. When providing content view controllers one at a time,
>   you use the `setViewControllers(_:direction:animated:completion:)`
>   method to set the current content view controllers. To support
>   gesture-based navigation, you must provide your view controllers using
>   a data source object. The data source for a page view controller is
>   responsible for providing the content view controllers on demand and
>   must conform to the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` protocol. The
>   delegate object—an object that conforms to the
>   `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` protocol—provides some appearance-related
>   information and receives notifications about gesture-initiated
>   transitions. This class is generally used as-is, but can also be
>   subclassed.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You can return nil from a delegate method to notify the page controller about last view controller.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such property on UIPageViewController. However, you can use UIScrollView for this purpose and instantiate all the views on install time. Also there are many third party frameworks you can use instead.